# xdebug-waiting for incoming connection with ide key

Tags: php, xdebug

I am using xDebug. but i can not debug the entire project. I can debug start URL page breakpoints. But when i step over lines it shows the login page and when i submit login page i can not reach next break point. In variables window it shows " Waiting for incoming connection with ide key ''. My configuration of php.ini for xdebug:

```
[XDebug]
    zend_extension="/usr/lib/php5/20121212+lfs/xdebug.so"
    xdebug.remote_enable=1
    xdebug.remote_port="9001"
    xdebug.profiler_enable=1
    xdebug.profiler_output_dir="home/tmp"
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add a line in php.ini:

```
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
```

My hope that this approach be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

you should setup phpstorm's DBG proxy
[image]

see: [refer link](http://www.cnblogs.com/cxscode/p/7045944.html)

Answer (score 0):

Because Xdebug needs either a cookie `XDEBUG_SESSION` or a query string in url `XDEBUG_SESSION_START` and the value is the value of your `Waiting for incoming connection with ide key`.

You may miss both of them from your login page.

ref: https://xdebug.org/docs/remote , search `HTTP Debug Sessions`